# "Daily vote limit reached; please come back in *x* hours" shows when you use your final vote

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, voting-limits

I just cast my last vote of the day. But when I did, I received this message:

[image: Daily vote limit reached; come back in 2 hours]

> Daily vote limit reached; come back in 2 hours

However, this was my last vote. I don't need to come back in 2 hours! The vote still stands.

The box should probably only appear if I *cannot* vote anymore, or the wording should be changed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think it's good that it is shown on your last vote. It's not saying "Come back in 2 hours to make this vote count", it's saying "Come back in 2 hours to start voting again". That way, you know you've used up your votes and how long you need to wait before you can vote again without needing to fail a vote.

If a wording change is needed, I think it would actually be in the first sentence. I'd suggest summat like the following,  to hopefully illustrate more clearly that the limit was attained post-vote.

> Daily vote limit now reached; come back in 2 hours.

Comment: Same here. This is by-design I think

Comment: I'd upvote you for "Daily vote limit now reached", but I can't for obvious reasons :-)